# jquery launch a button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, buttonclick

I am very new to jquery and javascript.So I have an aspx page with a button. Clicking that opens a jquery dialog. This dialog is a div. This div contains some controls,textboxes and 2 ASP image buttons. I have to use image buttons. Clicking that should launch the code on my .vb page.

```
My Html
<div id="divModal" title="Enter Truck Details" style="width:100px;">
<table><tr><td>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnCommand="btnAdd_Command"   ImageUrl="~/internal/images/add.gif" /> <br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="bntCancel" runat="server" OnCommand="bntCancel_Command" ImageUrl="~/internal/images/cancel.gif" /> 
 <td></tr></table>
```

My Vb page code

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
 ...

 End Sub
```

My jquery script

```
function addBoard() {
        $("#divModal").dialog();

    }
```

EDIT: When I click that btnAdd on my jquery dialog, then nothing happens.I put a breakpoint in my vb code but it is never hit. This is my question.

Comment: Good for you, but is there a question or did you just want to tell us what your code does ?

Comment: @adeneo.Oops. Yes.When I click that btnAdd on my jquery dialog, then nothing happens.I put a breakpoint in my vb code but it is never hit.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why are you using an ASP.NET server control to trigger a javascript function?

Comment: I think the problem may be the way the dialog moves the div.  It is probably messing with the javascript that asp.net injects in the page

Comment: whats in your VB code? I see that you are using Command, but are you using command name/command arguments? Why not just use onClick?

Comment: Does your dialog open when you run  $("#divModal").dialog(); from your browser console? Have you included jqueryui library?

Comment: @all. My button click was not happening because the dialog created by jQuery was becoming a completely different iframe. It had no connection to the .vb code behind. To overcome that I am not using a jquery dialog anymore. I am using a radwindow. It seems to work correctly for now.